# Flask-WTF not validating

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I made a WTForms for my Flask Website however the it just wont validate. I have made other flask WTForms before and they all seemed to work but this one just wont work

forms.py

```
class UpdateForm(FlaskForm):
    picture = FileField('Update Profile Picture', validators=[FileAllowed(['jpeg', 'jpg', 'png'])])
    username = StringField("Username", validators=[], render_kw={"placeholder": f"Enter username"})
    email = StringField("Email", validators=[Email()], render_kw={"placeholder": "Enter email"})
    submit = SubmitField('Update')

    def validate_username(self, username):
        if username.data is not None:
            user = User.query.filter_by(username=username.data).first()
            if user:
                raise ValidationError('Username is already taken.')

    def validate_email(self, email):
        if email.data is not None:
            emailL = User.query.filter_by(email=email.data).first()
            if emailL:
               raise ValidationError('Email is already taken.')
            else:
                raise ValidationError('Enter a valid email.')
```

I have done these methods before but this one is really not working and its not even giving me an error.

routes.py

```
@app.route('/settings/edit-profile', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def edit_profile():
    if not current_user.is_authenticated:
        flash('This process requires login.', 'failure')
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
    else:
        form = UpdateForm()
        if request.method == "POST" and form.validate_on_submit():
            print(form.username.data)
            print(form.email.data)
            pfp = url_for('static', filename=f'pfplib/{current_user.pfp}')
            return render_template("Settings/edit-profile.html", pfp=pfp, form=form)
        pfp = url_for('static', filename=f'pfplib/{current_user.pfp}')
        return render_template("Settings/edit-profile.html", pfp=pfp, form=form)
```

html file

```
<form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {{ form.csrf_token }}
            {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
            <div class="main-content">
                <div class="pfp-change">
                    <div class="container-pfp">
                        <img src="{{ pfp }}">
                        <div class="pick-div">
                            <input type="file">
                            <i class="fa fa-camera" style="color: #ffffff"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="edit-profile-form">
                    <div class="username-column">
                        {{ form.username.label(class="head-label") }}
                        {% if form.username.errors %}
                            {{ form.username(class="string-field") }}
                            {% print(error) %}
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                <span>{{ error }}</span>
                            </div>
                        {% else %}
                            {{ form.username(class="string-field", value=current_user.username) }}
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>
                    <div class="email-column">
                        {{ form.email.label(class="head-label") }}
                        {{ form.email(class="string-field", value=current_user.email) }}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="submit-div">
                {{ form.submit(class="btn-gradient submit-btn-1") }}
            </div>
        </form>
```

Hope someone can help fast
THANKING u SOOO SOOO SOO MUCH IF you can find a fix

Comment: With 'updating', what exactly do you mean? Is it simply getting the information found in your form, as you are doing, or 'updating' a database?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly what is causing your issue, but I think I have done a very similar thing to what you are trying to accomplish, so I can share with you what worked for me and hopefully it works for you too:

**My Form Validation**

```
class EditProfileForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('Username', validators=[DataRequired()])
    about_me = TextAreaField('About me', validators=[Length(min=0, max=250)])
    website_link = StringField('Link your website', validators=[Optional(), URL(message='This is not a valid link, make sure you enter the entire URL')])
    submit = SubmitField('Apply Changes')


    def __init__(self, original_username, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EditProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.original_username = original_username

    def validate_username(self, username):
        if username.data != self.original_username:
            user = User.query.filter(User.username.ilike(self.username.data)).first()
            if user is not None:
                raise ValidationError('This username is already taken')
            if ' ' in username.data:
                raise ValidationError('Your username may not contain spaces.')
```

Note: I did not have an email validation, but it would follow the same form as my username validation.

**My routes.py**

```
@app.route('/edit_profile/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def edit_profile():
    form = EditProfileForm(current_user.username)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        current_user.username = form.username.data
        current_user.about_me = form.about_me.data
        current_user.website = form.website_link.data
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Your changes have been saved.')
        return redirect(url_for('main.user', username = current_user.username))
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        form.username.data = current_user.username
        form.about_me.data = current_user.about_me
```

**My relevant HTML**

```
<form action="" method="post">
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        <p>
            <div id="changePPLink"><a href="{{ url_for('main.pic_upload') }}" >Change your profile picture</a><br></div>
            <div id="changePasswordLink"><a href="{{ url_for('auth.change_password') }}">Change your password</a><br></div>
            {{ form.username.label }}<br>
            {{ form.username(size=32, id="usernameField") }}<br>
            {% for error in form.username.errors %}
            <span style="color: red;">{{ error }}</span>
            {% endfor %}
        </p>
        <p>
            {{ form.about_me.label }}<br>
            {{ form.about_me(cols=50, rows=4, id="aboutMeField") }}<br>
            {% for error in form.about_me.errors %}
            <span style="color: red;">{{ error }}</span>
            {% endfor %}
        </p>
        <p>
            {{ form.website_link.label }}<br>
            {{ form.website_link(size=32, id="websiteField") }} <br>
            {% for error in form.website_link.errors %}
            <span style="color: red;">{{ error }}</span>
            {% endfor %}
        </p>

        <p>{{ form.submit() }}</p>

    </form>
```

From this I don't see many differences between are code, but there are a few that could be causing your issue.
1.I have an **init** function in my form
2. my query for user in my username_validation uses ilike which makes it case insensitive
3. I made data required on the username field, and just inputted the users current username as the default of the form, this meant I didn't need to check if there was data in the field, I just checked if the data matched the current username.
4. Our routes are slightly different, I just look for form.validate_on_submit(), but I imagine you are using your method for all of your forms that are working, so that's probably not where the problem is

5.Our displaying of error messages is different

So you can try to input some of the methods I used into your case and see if that helps at all.
It may also be useful to know what happens when you try to submit the form, does it submit no matter what is in the fields? or does it not submit at all? that might help find where the problem is.

I hope that helps, even just a bit, Sorry if it does not!

Answer (score 0):

You could add the novalidate property in the html Form. Maybe the browsers validation is blocking your own.